# .map JSON based on specific value

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am trying to call Javascript's `.map()` method on a backbone collection that contains a JSON that looks like this:

```
[
  {"from":"houston","to":"austin"},
  {"from":"omaha", "to":"kc"}
]
```

My backbone model looks like this:

```
var ChoiceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
  var choiceModel = new ChoiceModel({
    a:'from',
    z:'omaha'
  })
```

The problem is every JSON document I'm interested in has the Key "from" instead of the city I'm interested in. Below I am trying to filter all the JSONs with the "from" value of "omaha".

```
var aVar = this.model.get('a');
var zVar = this.model.get('z');

return this.collection.map(function(model){
      return {
        a: model.get(aVar[zVar])
};
```

Ideally I would be able to later call variable 'a' it would only return: `{"from":"omaha", "to":"kc"}`.

I've tried a few variations of the code above to no avail. How can I `.map()` on JSON values?

Comment: Have you tried with `_.filter` instead?

Comment: No `_.filter` doesn't work for some reason, I don't know a ton about backbone collections, but `.map()` seems to be the standard to reduce JSONs with.

Comment: `.map()` and `.reduce()` are two entirely different things. With map you end up with an array containing the same number of elements, with reduce you end up with a single value.

Comment: That's fair, maybe I should be using .reduce, but how should the key value pair be structured?